# Find a self-adjoint operator with $[0, 1] \subseteq \sigma_{sing} (A)$.

Tags: functional-analysis, spectral-theory, self-adjoint-operators

I am asked to find a self-adjoint operator $A$ on a Hilbert space $H$ such that $[0, 1] \subseteq \sigma_{sing} (A)$.

Here, $\sigma_{sing}(A) = \sigma (A|_{H_{sing}})$.

(EDIT: The definition(s) are given here:
$H_{sing} = \{ v \in H : \mu_v \mbox{ is continuous singular w.r.t. Lebesgue measure on }  \mathbb{R} \}$, where $\mu_v$ is the measure induced from the positive functional $T_v : C(\sigma(A)) \to \mathbb{R}$ defined by $T_v f = \langle f(A) v, v \rangle$)

I was given a hint that find a multiplicity free (i.e. has a cyclic vector) with spectral measure as a weighted sum of translated Cantor measure.

So I guess the measure needed should be something like $$\nu = \sum_{n = 1}^\infty \frac{1}{2^n} \mu_n$$ where $\mu_n (E) = \mu (E - n)$ and $\mu$ is the self-similar probability measure on the Cantor set.

But I have no idea how to construct such $A$.

Any hints are appreciated.

Comment: What is $H_{sing}$?

Comment: $H_{sing} = \{ v \in H : \mu_v \mbox{ is continuous singular w.r.t. Lebesgue measure on }  \mathbb{R} \}$, where $\mu_v$ is the measure induced from the positive functional $T_v: C(\sigma(A)) \to \mathbb{R}$ defined by $T_v f = \langle f(A) v, v \rangle$

Comment: Take $(Tf)(x)=xf(x)$ on $L^2((0,1),d\mu),$ where $\mu$ is a singular probability measure with support equal $[0,1].$ The function$11$ is a cyclic vector by the Weierstrass theorem.